# Switching Pages with one pictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to switch between 2 Pages with one pictureBox. I do not know how to do something like that.
I did try something like

```cs
        private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(settings1.Visible)
            {
                isDisplayed = true;
                pictureBox2.Hide();
            }
            settings1.Show();
            settings1.BringToFront();
        }

        private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Hide();
            pictureBox2.Show();
            pictureBox2.BringToFront();
            settings1.Hide();
        }
```

Maybe i am doing it completly wrong. Any Ideas?

Comment: Hint 1: You can't click on a hidden control. Hint 2: No need to ever hide the bottom PBox..

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way that's in keeping with your original approach:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PictureBox boxA, boxB;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.boxA = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.boxA.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        this.boxA.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.boxA.Name = "boxA";
        this.boxA.Click += Box_Click;
        this.Controls.Add(this.boxA);

        this.boxB = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.boxB.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        this.boxB.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.boxB.Name = "boxB";
        this.boxB.Click += Box_Click;
        this.Controls.Add(this.boxB);

    }

    private void Box_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox box = sender as PictureBox;
        box.SendToBack();
    }
}
```

Comment: One of many ways; but: `DockStyle.Fill` may make no sense. Better align the Locations and Sizes..

Comment: The Postion i set is so normaly right but if i do `this.boxA.Location = new Point(565, 10);` its like below my Panel

Comment: The only point here was to demonstrate having both controls visible and calling `SendToBack` on the one you clicked to cycle between them.  The Dock thing is irrelevant (but makes for a functional example with minimal distracting code.)